# Linux Command login and Updating system

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, security

I have a strange thing happening to one of our servers when I login with term I get

```
9 packages can be updated.
9 updates are security updates.
```

So I do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

but it doesn't install anything see below

```
~$ sudo apt-get update

Ign ...... trusty InRelease
Hit htt......
Reading package lists... Done

~$ sudo apt-get upgrade

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-headers-generic linux-headers-virtual linux-image-virtual
  linux-virtual
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks

Ado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packages which are held back are related to the kernel and won't be upgraded with the `apt-get upgrade` command. To upgrade these you should use:

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`